# Desktop Shortcut Icon is different than Application Icon

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have created a Call Log Dialog and I have added an Icon to help make the application more noticeable to fellow coworkers.

My icon is in the .rc file as:

```
IDI_CABINET             ICON                    "cabinet.ico"
```

and I load the icon with:

```
m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDI_CABINET);
```

and set with:

```
SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);
```

When I build a Release Version and find the the .exe file for my application the icon appears just as I want it; however, when I create a desktop shortcut the image defaults to some windows application icon. If I click on the shortcut it opens and runs the program without issue. Is there something else I need to declare inside the program to change the icon for shortcuts as well? This also does not correctly appear when the application is sent to the taskbar.

*Edit I am using Windows 7 in case that matters.

Comment: This is completely Visual Studio specific and has little if anything to do with C++.

Comment: @JeffS I think he wants you to remove the c++ tag ;-) Did you check with a resource editor which icons and in which order have been put into the exe ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ok I'll remove the C++ tag. I really wasn't sure where the error would be located. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Marged Yes I noticed the order of the icon mattered and I removed all the ones I wasn't using so it is actually the only icon in the rc file but still loads a different icon for shortcuts

Comment: @Marged: I never said that!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I thought you were, and I would have supported this demand ;-)

Comment: The in some sense first (AFAIK Microsoft never documented the sense) icon resource is used as application icon. Give it a low id like 100.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I gave it a lower ID and the problem still remains The icon appears alongside the application in the file but not when it is created as a shortcut